# Setting the LOCALE_ID in Angular without using a specific URL

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

[In this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#build-for-multiple-locales) it is explained how to set the LOCALE_ID using the url (e.g. https://myapp.com/**fr**/).

What I want is to use the same url for all locale (https://myapp.com/) and set the LOCALE_ID depending on the choice of the user (select).